# Display Laravel Data with Relationships in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, axios, vue-router

I am building an SPA with Vue.js, Vue Router, Axios and Laravel. I have a foreign key in my User table to identify a users "location." I'm trying to pull the location_name from the Locations table using the foreign key in the User's table. The console shows the location to be null.

**Relationship in User Model**

```php
<?php

public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\location','location');
}
```

**Relationship in Location Model**

```php
<?php

public function User()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function show($id){
    $User = User::with('location')->find($id);

    return response()->json($User);
}
```

**Script**

```
 export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            tech:[]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/tech/' + this.$route.params.id).then(response=>this.tech=response.data);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<input type="text" v-model="tech.location.location_name">
```

**routes.js**

```
   let routes = [
    {
        path:'/',
        component:require('./views/dashboard/dashboard')
    },

    {
        path:'/locations',
        component:require('./views/locations/locations')
    },

    {
        path:'/allLocations',
        component:require('./views/locations/allLocations')
    },
    {
        path:'/inActiveLocations',
        component:require('./views/locations/inActiveLocations')
    }
    ,
    {
        path:'/newLocation',
        component:require('./views/locations/newLocation')
    }
    ,
    {
        path:'/location/:id',
        component:require('./views/locations/location')
    }
    ,
    {
        path:'/editLocation/:id',
        component:require('./views/locations/editLocation')
    }
    ,
    {
        path:'/techs',
        component:require('./views/techs/techs')
    }
    ,
    {
        path:'/createTech',
        component:require('./views/techs/createTech')
    },
    {
        path:'/tech/:id',
        component:require('./views/techs/tech')
    }
```

**web.php**

```
 <?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

/* Locations*/
Route::post('/location','locationController@store');
Route::get('/locations','locationController@index');
Route::get('/inActiveLocations','locationController@inActiveLocations');
Route::get('/allLocations','locationController@allLocations');
Route::get('/location/{id}','locationController@show');
Route::get('/editLocation/{id}','locationController@edit');
Route::patch('/updateLocation/{id}','locationController@update');



/*Users*/
Route::get('/techs','techController@index');
Route::post('/tech','techController@store');
Route::get('/tech/{id}','techController@show');
```

Comment: Debugging 101: 1) I haven't used axios, but have you tried `console.log`ing the response.data variable? With vue-resource for example, the data would be under `response.body`. 2) Are there any errors in console? 3) Are you sure that the relationship is correct and returns location? Perhaps the class name / namespace is incorrect? 4) Does a user with the supplied ID exist? Does the location, this user belongs to, exist? EDIT: you did check the console, sorry.

Comment: What sticks out is that your first relation uses `'App\location'` as class name, which is, by convention, not what a class should be named like. Class names should follow `PascalCase` notation. For better code stability, use `public function location() { return $this->belongsTo(Location::class); }`.

Comment: please show your routes @TA

Comment: @saurabhkamble I have added the routes.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make some changes to your code. You are trying to retrieve property rather than the relation. To get the location you will need to make the following change.

```
public function show($id){
    $User = User::find($id);
    $response = $User;
    $response['location'] = $User->location;
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: I made that change. That got the foreign key to display. Thanks. Any suggestions on how to display the location_name from the locations table based on that key?

Comment: I'd check what `$User` (from your code) and `$response` (from Dhavals code) return using Tinker. I wonder if `tech.location.location_name` should be `tech.location.name`. Also note that Laravel class names should be in StudlyCaps (in your case, simply Location with a capital L), but PHP variable names usually start with a lower case letter (`$user`).

Comment: For location_name, you will have to do something like  $response['location_name'] = $User->location->location_name. Also followthe conventions as @Pida said.

Comment: Manually assigning the `location` relationship to a property is not necessary. `toArray()`, which is called by `response()->json($data)`, will also return relationships properly if they were eager loaded with `with('relationship')` (which is the case in the question's code).